# Java Swing KeyBinding with multiple key combination

Tags: java, swing

I want to print to the console a message when both G key and A key are pressed. This should be a pretty easy task but for some reason i cannot achieve this, and cannot find any useful  example online. I tried various syntaxes to describe the keystroke i wish to use, but none worked. This is my minimal code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class TestKeyBinding extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestKeyBinding();
    }

    public TestKeyBinding() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                JLabel l = new JLabel();
                l.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("G A"), "ga");
                l.getActionMap().put("ga", new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("test ga");
                    }
                });
                l.setOpaque(true);
                l.setBackground(Color.red);
                
                frame.add(l);

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't check for multiple KeyStrokes at one time. You can only check if the modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Control) have been pressed together with another key. Read the `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String)` API for examples of building a KeyStroke with modifiers. So if you want to check for "G and A" you need two separate bindings. One approach would be to add the key chaaracter to a Map in the In the keyPressed binding. Then when you have two characters in the map you can check to see if they are "G and A". If so, then you invoke your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please write a bit of code to route me towards the right direction?

Comment: Check out the `KeyboardAnimation` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). It demonstrates how you can combine two key events, like right/up to provide diagonal movement. Your code should be simpler since you don't need the animation logic.

Comment: Just took at look at it.. i think i will rethink the key combination i had in mind because this suggested approach (if it is the only approach) is overkill for what i need. I am surprised that one has to spit blood to intercept 2 keys pressing

Comment: There is always more than one approach. The key is that you somehow need to track the state of the first key paressed. Then when the second key is pressed you check the state of the first key.